# Service Bus for Windows Server SAS authentication over http

Tags: authentication, authorization, servicebus

I have a question about client authentication on Windows Service Bus for Windows Server using the REST API. For my solution the clients need to communicate with the Service Bus Queues over HTTP and I can not use Windows Integrated Security. That leaves me with SAS. I have looked at the Microsoft Page where Authentication is described for Service Bus 1.1 but can't figure out how the client can acquire the access token. I know that you can acquire the token calling the STS using the Microsoft.ServiceBus.TokenProvider but that is not an option for my clients. So is there a way to acquire a token providing an access key and name over http to the Service Bus?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sample (linked below) that shows how you can create your own token. With SAS you do not need a service to issue tokens, and can pre-create and distribute them to clients:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Shared-Access-Signature-0a88adf8/sourcecode?fileId=81470&pathId=1811741783